# Instalação PhoneGap

Tags: apache-cordova

Após rodar `sudo npm install -g phonegap` e tentar criar um projeto com `phonegap create my-app` o retorno do terminal é este;

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'bplist-parser'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous>     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/cordova-common/src/ConfigChanges/ConfigFile.js:20:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Ja tentei rodar `clean, check` porem nada resolve.
(Já tenho o node e o npm instalado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este problema é decorrente de uma má instalação, pelo que entendi, basta você dar um update `sudo npm update -g` , assim ele forçará o upgrade, portanto voltando a funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta instalar o cordova

```
sudo npm install cordova
```

Depois tenta criar um projeto

```
cordova create projeto
```

Answer (score 0):

Tive o mesmo problema para usar o "IONIC FRAMEWORK",a minha questão foi solucionado instalando o Cordova

```
$sudo npm install cordova
```

conferi qual a versão do cordova

```
$cordova -v
```

logo em seguida usei o UPDATE

```
$sudo npm update -g
```

fonte https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/